# Measures with Fourier transform in $L^p$, $p > 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a non-zero finite Borel measure with compact support on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

**Facts**

If $\widehat{\mu} \in L^2$, then $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure with an $L^2$ density.

If $\widehat{\mu} \in L^1$, then $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure with an $L^{\infty}$ (in fact, continuous) density.

If $\widehat{\mu} \in L^p$, for some $1 < p < 2$, then $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure with an $L^{p'}$ density, $p'=p/(p-1)$. (The proof is basically the same as the $L^1$ case; just using Hausdorff-Young at the end).

**Question**

If $\widehat{\mu} \in L^p$, for some $2 < p \leq \infty$, then what can be said about $\mu$?

Comment: If $g(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{-2i \pi \xi x} d\mu(x) \in L^2$ then $\mu(A) = \int_A f(x)dx$ for some $f \in L^2$ ($f = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[g]$).

Comment: @user1952009 I want $p>2$.

Comment: Yes but the hint is that we are looking at $f = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[g]$. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#On_other_Lp)

Comment: @user1952009 If $g \in L^p$ ($p>2$), the Fourier transform of $g$ is defined only in the distributional sense. Katznelson is cited there. Are you saying look at Katznelson?

Comment: Yes, look at the Fourier transform on $L^p,p>2$ .If you know the distributions then the operator $\varphi \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \varphi(x) d\mu(x)$ is a distribution, so there is a distribution $T$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \varphi(x) d\mu(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \varphi(x) T(x)dx$ ie $\mu(A) =\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} 1_{x \in A} T(x)dx= \int_A T(x)dx$ and $d\mu(x) = T(x)dx$ and $\hat{\mu} = \hat{T}$. Not every distribution $T$ gives a measure $\mu(A) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} 1_{x \in A} T(x)dx$  only those of order $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The knowledge that $\hat \mu \in L^\infty$ adds nothing new, since the Fourier transform of *any* finite measure is in $L^\infty$.

If $\hat \mu\in L^p$ with $2<p<\infty$, then $\mu$ has no atoms, i.e., $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for every $x$. See [this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/64202).

Further along these lines, being in $L^p$ with not very large $p$ precludes $\mu$ from being supported on a lower-dimensional surface. Specifically, if $\hat \mu\in L^{2d/k}$, then $\mu$ cannot be supported on a $k$-dimensional $C^1$-smooth surface. This is a theorem of Agranovsky and  Narayanan, [quoted in this thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07005) which also has other references to literature on the topic.

Comment: I'm unsure of something about the  Agranovsky and Narayanan result and the similar result in the thesis. The result is stated in terms of $f in L^p$ and the support of $\widehat{f}$. What is the relationship between support of $\mu$ and the support of $\widehat{f}$, where $f=\widehat{\mu}$. Must they be equal?

Comment: Please ignore issues of reflection (i.e., $\widehat{\widehat{f}}(x) = f(-x)\neq f(x)$) for now.

Comment: I realized I should be thinking in terms of distributions. Then it makes sense.

Comment: I am putting this here for my own reference. $\widehat{\mu}$ is uniformly continuous. So $\widehat{\mu} \in L^p$ implies $\widehat{\mu}(\xi) \rightarrow 0$ as $\xi \rightarrow \infty$ implies $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x$. The last implicationcomes from the link in the second sentence of the answer: Weiner's Theorem.